# Child module function modified in script scope reverts when execution reaches child module- by design?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

A script (.ps1) imports ModuleA which imports ModuleB.
From the script I can see a function from ModuleB (with Get-Command), but it is listed as belonging to ModuleA. I can also modify/remove the function.
When execution gets into ModuleA, the function from ModuleB  is listed as belonging to ModuleB (via Get-Command) and reverts to the original state.

Is this by design?

### example:

### Invoke-Greeting.ps1

```
Import-Module .\Import-First.psm1

Get-Command -Module "Import-First"     # Write-Greetings and Write-Goodbye
Get-Command -Module "Import-Second"    # no functions found
Get-Command -Name "Write-Goodbye"      # Write-Goodbye (module = Import-First) ***is this by design?***

Remove-Item "function:\Write-Goodbye"

Get-Command -Module "Import-First"     # Write-Greetings
Get-Command -Module "Import-Second"    # no functions found
Get-Command -Name "Write-Goodbye"      # error: function doesn't exist (expected)

Write-Greetings
```

---

### Import-First.psm1

```
Import-Module .\Import-Second.psm1
function Write-Greetings
{
    Write-Host "hello world!"              # hello world!
    Get-Command -Module "Import-First"     # Write-Greetings
    Get-Command -Module "Import-Second"    # Write-GoodBye
    Get-Command -Name "Write-GoodBye"      # Write-GoodBye (module = Import-Second) ***module changed since execution scope changed***

    Write-GoodBye
}
```

---

### Import-Second.psm1

```
function Write-Goodbye
{    
    Write-Host "bye bye!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When you import a module within a module, the nested module's functions act as though they are part of the parent module.  When you import a module, you can export specific members of that module into the global scope.  Deleting those globally scoped objects doesn't effect the internal module.

I recommend not nesting modules.  Import each module separately.  It is best to create a custom `Import-Module.ps1` script for each module which first import's that module's dependencies, then imports the module itself.  So, in your case,

## Import-First.ps1

```
& Import-Second.ps1
Import-Module First.psm1
```

## Import-Second.ps1

```
Import-Module Second.psm1
```

## Invoke-Greeting.ps1

```
& .\Import-First.ps1

Get-Command -Module "First"     # Write-Greetings and Write-Goodbye
Get-Command -Module "Second"    # no functions found
Get-Command -Name "Write-Goodbye"      # Write-Goodbye (module = Import-First) ***is this by design?***

& .\Import-Second.ps1

Get-Command -Module "First"     # Write-Greetings
Get-Command -Module "Second"    # Write-Goodbye found
Get-Command -Name "Write-Goodbye"      # function exists because it is in Second module.

Write-Greetings
```

You shouldn't author modules that have conflicting names.  The second module will always overwrite the first modules functions/cmdlets/variables, if they are named similar between them.  You can use the `Import-Module`'s `-NoClobber` parameter to prevent code from getting overwritten.